# Specifying the Hibernate Naming Strategy in JHipster

Tags: jhipster

In a Microservice architecture, you tend to have several time the same entity (ex. Customer in MicroService1 and Customer in MicroService2). So when you check your databases, you quickly get lost ("which database I am looking at").

It would be nice to be able to prefix the table names. By default, everything stays the same, but if we want, we could prefix all our tables (ex. ms1_customer, ms2_customer). Either using the [HibernateNaming](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/NamingStrategy.html) strategy (there is a Spring Boot extension, [SpringNamingStrategy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/hibernate/SpringNamingStrategy.html)), or just by adding @Table(name="ms1_customer").

WDYT ?

Answer (score 0):

You can already specify the table name in the `.jhipster` json entity files and you can go further (e.g. specifying column names) by using https://github.com/bastienmichaux/generator-jhipster-db-helper module currently under development.